# php query alwaysfalse no matter what

Tags: php

I have tried to read and do (incorporate) anything I find on here. But I have not found the solution. I'm using wamp server and I have a user table with 2 users one with email and password as test and test1 and no matter what I try the if statement always returns false.

```
<?php

 $user = "root";
 $pass = "";
 $db = "testdb";

 $db = new mysqli("localhost", $user, $pass, $db) or die("did not work");

 echo "it connected";

 $email = "test";
 $pass1 = "test1";
 $qry = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = " '. $email .' " AND password = " '.$pass1.' " ';

 $result = mysqli_query($db, $qry) or die(" did not query");

 $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

 if( $count > 0)
     echo "        found user   ";
 else 
     echo "    did not find user or password";

 ?>
```

I have tried to augment mysqli_num_rows but then it comes out always true

Comment: change your query this way, Select * from user where email = 'email' and password = 'password'. Currently its in double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to eliminate the blank spaces in the encapsulation of the variable

```
<?php

$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "testdb";

$db = new mysqli("localhost", $user, $pass, $db) or die("did not work");

echo "it connected";

$email = "test";
$pass1 = "test1";
$qry = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = "'. $email .'" AND password = "'.$pass1.'"';

$result = mysqli_query($db, $qry) or die(" did not query");

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if( $count > 0)
    echo "        found user   ";
else 
    echo "    did not find user or password";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have spaces in your query around your variables:

```
" '. $email .' "
```

change to:

```
"'. $email .'"
```

MySQL will take those spaces literally when it searches for matches.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysqli class version then you should use like below :

```
<?php

$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "testdb";

$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $user, $pass, $db);

$email = "test";
$pass1 = "test1";

$qry = sprintf('SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = "%s" AND password = "%s"',$email,$pass1);
$result = $mysqli->query($qry);
$count = $result->num_rows;

 if( $count > 0)
     echo "        found user   ";
 else 
     echo "    did not find user or password";

$mysqli->close();
?>
```